# Is a parameter passed to a view defined only inside a initialize function?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

```
var plistview = new CollectionListView(productcollection);
```

in the above line i am passing a collection to a view.

in the CollectionListView i am trying to write a function that makes use of this collection passed. But the collection is defined only in the initialize function and we need to call the other function through the initialize(). But i want that function to be fired onClick by defining event.

```
categoryList: function(collection){
                          var length = collection.length;
                          alert(length);
                          },
```

the above function returns length if collection is passed to it from initialize. but 
returns undefined when called independently from event

```
events : {
        'click #category' : 'categoryList'
         },
```

I want the value passed to be defined through out the view even if its fired independently. 
Please shed some light.

Comment: `new CollectionListView({ collection: productcollection })` would be more common, then you'd get `this.collection` for free inside the view: http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor

Comment: do you know using options? if it is try with the code : `new CollectionListView({ collection: productcollection, myNewParam: newParam })` and change initialize like that:  `initialize: function(options){ var myNewParam = options.myNewPAram;}`